# Using NLog with multiple app instances

Tags: .net, clickonce, nlog

I have a ClickOnce-deployed WinForms app. Users can launch multiple instances of the app. Each instance should write to a separate log file. I need to be able to discover the current instance's log file at runtime, so I can use it for sending out crash reports, etc.

Now I can't get around the multiple instances requirement. (What they really need is a tabbed UI, but this is one big mess of a legacy app, and I just can't implement it right now.)

In general logging works, but separate app instances overwrite the same file.

I have tried to add a time stamp to the log file name, but that didn't work:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" 
              fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/MyCompany/CRM/crm_${longdate}.log"
              deleteOldFileOnStartup ="true"
              layout="${longdate} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"/>
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the context of your application, can you know a valid (and meaningful) name for that instance?  Can the multiple instances be launched with a command line parameter that represents the name of the application?  If you can "know" a useful name for the application, then you could store the name in the GlobalDiagnosticsContext and use the GlobalDiagnosticsContext LayoutRenderer to build your filename.

So, your configuration might look something like this:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" 
          fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/MyCompany/CRM/crm_${gdc:item=application}.log"
          deleteOldFileOnStartup ="true"
          layout="${longdate} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"/>
```

In your application startup logic, you would set the gdc like this:

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.set("application", GetApplicationNameFromCommandLineArgs());
```

Each application will write to its own log file, named based on the command line parameter.

Good luck!

Comment: Hmm...interesting. I can't see this working with a command line parameter, because the user opens the instances with the same shortcut. But I could generate a unique name for each instance (e.g., including the startup time) and then use this via GlobalDiagnosticsContext, right?

Comment: Yes.  As long as there is something unique.  You could even use a guid to name the logfile (ie create a guid and put that in the GDC).  The only problem with naming the logfile this way is that it will be hard to differentiate the files by name.  In effect you will get log files like A.log, B.log, C.log, etc.  But, if your application cannot provide more specific identifying information, then you just have to live with that limitation.

Comment: OK, that's cool. Startup time should be good enough as a differentiator. I hope I find the time to try this out later today or tomorrow and will accept your answer then.